# CentOS Failover Cluster - SIOCADDRT: No such process (when adding a loopback)

Tags: networking, centos, failover, centos5

I'm trying to configure two web servers for a load balancing server. The load balancing aspect works fine (it sees both server, kills 'em if it needs to, and seems to direct traffic fine). The only issue is with the servers looping:

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo:0**

```
DEVICE=lo:0
IPADDR=<Virtual IP>
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopback
```

Everytime I try a "*service network restart*" I get a **SIOCADDRT: No such process** when loading the loopback interface.

Anyone have an idea what's causing this?

Comment: How many interfaces on the system?  If it's just a primary interface and lo, can you show us the ifcfg-eth0 file, too?  It would be useful if you could include addresses in the file; if they both share the same first two octets, just replace them with "10.10" or something.  The error you're getting often comes from `route`, so it would help to see the complete network configuration.

Comment: Forgot about this question... I resolved it by @larsks's answer, but ended up throwing in the towel when it decided to stop working (after it was working fine for an hour). I appreciate your comments though! Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everytime I try a "service network restart" I get a SIOCADDRT: No such
>   process when loading the loopback interface.

This typically comes from the `route` command, and means that you're trying to
set up a route via an invalid gateway.  For example, if I have:

```
# ip addr list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ac:6f:a6:bf:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global external
```

And then I try to add a route to 192.168.3.0 via 192.168.1.1, but accidentally
make a typo and enter the wrong gateway address:

```
# route add 192.168.3.0/24 gw 192.168.2.1
```

Then I get this:

```
SIOCADDRT: No such process
```

If instead of doing a `service network restart`, what happens if you just use `ifup lo:0`? Do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 2):

Add NO_ALIASROUTING=yes in your alias config, or in your parent device confg if you don't need routing for any alias. Check your ifup-aliases if it supports NO_ALIASROUTING. If not, setting GATEWAY="" in your alias config could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Note that /usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysconfig.txt says that the alias devices should not duplicate the information contained in the parent device.

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface-name> and
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface-name>:<alias-name>:

  The first defines an interface, and the second contains
  only the parts of the definition that are different in a
  "alias" (or alternative) interface.  For example, the
  network numbers might be different, but everything else
  might be the same, so only the network numbers would be
  in the alias file, but all the device information would
  be in the base ifcfg file.
```

It also says use `ONPARENT` instead of `ONBOOT`:

```
ONBOOT=yes|no (not valid for alias devices; use ONPARENT)

ONPARENT=yes|no
  Whether to bring up the device when the parent device is brought
  up.
  Default: yes
```

This makes me think that `ONBOOT=yes` is incorrect. What happens if you use `ONPARENT` instead?

```
DEVICE=lo:0
IPADDR=<Virtual IP>
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
```

Update:

Turns out this doesn't really matter. As larsks says, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-aliases` only checks for `ONPARENT=no`:

```
for FILE in ifcfg-${parent_device}:* ; do
   is_ignored_file "$FILE" && continue
   ini_env;
   . $FILE;
   [ -z "$DEVICE" ] && DEVICE=${FILE##ifcfg-}
   [ "$ONPARENT" != "no" -a "$ONPARENT" != "NO" ] && new_interface;
   unset DEVICE
done
```

Comment: ONBOOT=yes works just fine for alias interfaces, regardless of the documentation.   In fact, if you look at the `ifup-aliases` script, you'll see that it only checks for `ONPARENT=no`, so not setting it is the same as `ONPARENT=yes`.  Use the source!